# error en JSF: No se puede crear el bean administrado

Tags: java, jsf

Apenas empiezo a utilizar JSF y hago una practica de login, solo que sale el siguiente error, alguien que me ayude
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo mi código del archivo index.xhtml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Pagina del Login</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="Login del Sisrema"/></h1>
            <h:outputText value="Nombre de usuario:"/>
            <h:inputText id="txtNombre" value="#{LoginManagedBean.nombre}"/>
            
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <h:outputText value="Clave de usuario:"/>
            <h:inputSecret id="txtClave" value="#{LoginManagedBean.clave}"/>
            
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <h:commandButton value="Aceptar" action="#{LoginManagedBean.cmdEnviarAction}"/>
                        
        </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Mi código faces-config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>LoginManagedBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>beans.LoginManagedBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>nombre</property-name>
            <value>admin</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

y mi archivo LoginManagedBean.java

```html
package beans;


public class LoginManagedBean {

    
    public LoginManagedBean() {}
    
    private String nombre;
    private String clave;
    
    public String getClave(){
        return clave;
    }
    public void setClave (String clave){
        this.clave = clave;
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre (String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String cmdEnviarAction()
    {
        System.out.println("Nombre = " +getNombre());
        System.out.println("Clave = " +getClave());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si está utilizando `JSF 2.2` según su archivo `faces-config`:

```
<faces-config version="2.2 ..."
```

Por qué no utilizar anotaciones ?

```
import javax.faces.bean.*;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginManagedBean {
...
}
```

o con [CDI](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_built_in_scopes)

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginManagedBean {
...
}
```

Por defecto, y creo que ésto va también para el estilo viejo utilizando `faces-config` para declarar un managed bean, JSF lo que hace es crear una instancia de éste cuando sea requerido y el nombre de instancia es el mismo nombre de clase pero con la primera letra en minúscula, es decir que para acceder a `LoginManagedBean` a través de `Expression Language` sería:

```
#{loginManagedBean}
```

Por lo que puede que su error (si quiere seguir utilizando el estilo viejo de declaración de managed beans) puede que se arregle si le cambia el nombre a minúscula la primera letra:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>loginManagedBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>beans.LoginManagedBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  ...
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: gracias, buena aportacion